# Delete first line of file if it's empty

Tags: shell, unix, sed

How can I delete the first (!) line of a text file if it's empty, using e.g. sed or other standard UNIX tools. I tried this command:

```
sed '/^$/d' < somefile
```

But this will delete the first empty line, not the first line of the file, if it's empty. Can I give sed some condition, concerning the line number?

With Levon's answer I built this small script based on awk:

```
#!/bin/bash

for FILE in $(find some_directory -name "*.csv")
do
    echo Processing ${FILE}

    awk '{if (NR==1 && NF==0) next};1' < ${FILE} > ${FILE}.killfirstline
    mv ${FILE}.killfirstline ${FILE}

done
```

Comment: What do you mean by in-place? If you mean "generate no temp file", I actually don't care. I guess I can rename the resulting file afterwards.

Comment: Yes, I was wondering if you wanted to modify the file itself in-place.

Comment: Btw, I also tried `sed '1 /^$/d'`, because the sed manual says, commands can be restricted by prefixing them with a line number. However, my GNU sed does not like this. Any hints?

Comment: Sorry, I'm more comfortable with `awk`, not so much `sed` which I only use use occassionally.

Comment: I think the `awk` solution does what you want though, no?

Comment: Yes it does, but in-place /would/ be preferable. Although I can work around this restriction. Now I am more interested as to how sed might be able to do it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The simplest thing in sed is:

```
sed '1{/^$/d}'
```

Note that this does not delete a line that contains all blanks, but only a line that contains nothing but a single newline.  To get rid of blanks:

```
sed '1{/^ *$/d}'
```

and to eliminate all whitespace:

```
sed '1{/^[[:space:]]*$/d}'
```

Note that some versions of `sed` require a terminator inside the block, so you might need to add a semi-colon.  eg `sed '1{/^$/d;}'`

Comment: That's what I was looking for. I did not realize, I had to use the curly braces. sed's documentation is a bit lacking...

Comment: @Arne Once you decided to do it in-place and to use `sed`, you accepted the better answer. (And *I* learned a lot about `sed` today :) Glad it all worked out.

Comment: BSD/macOS sed expects newlines in the command; this works: `sed $'1{\n/^$/d\n}'

Comment: On macOS, It seems only the second `\n` is required: `sed $'1{/^$/d\n}'`.

Comment: You don't really need a newline in bsd sed, just a terminator.  This should work: `sed '1{/^$/d;}'` Answer edited.

Answer (score 4):

Using sed, try this:

```
sed -e '2,$b' -e '/^$/d' < somefile
```

or to make the change in place:

```
sed -i~ -e '2,$b' -e '/^$/d' somefile
```

Comment: Note that this answer doesn't require GNU sed like the others do.

Comment: You get a point for that. When I'm on a Solaris machine, I'll use your answer. On my Mac, I have gsed installed, but it's nice to have a solution that works with BSD sed as well.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have to do this in-place, you can use `awk` and redirect the output into a different file.

```
awk '{if (NR==1 && NF==0) next};1' somefile
```

This will print the contents of the file except if it's the first line (`NR == 1`) and it doesn't contain any data (`NF == 0`).

`NR` the current line number,`NF` the number of fields on a given line separated by blanks/tabs

E.g.,

```
$ cat -n data.txt
     1  
     2  this is some text
     3  and here
     4  too
     5  
     6  blank above
     7  the end

$ awk '{if (NR==1 && NF==0) next};1' data.txt | cat -n
     1  this is some text
     2  and here
     3  too
     4  
     5  blank above
     6  the end
```

and

```
cat -n data2.txt
     1  this is some text
     2  and here
     3  too
     4  
     5  blank above
     6  the end

$ awk '{if (NR==1 && NF==0) next};1' data2.txt | cat -n
     1  this is some text
     2  and here
     3  too
     4  
     5  blank above
     6  the end
```

*Update*:

This `sed` solution should also work for in-place replacement:

```
sed -i.bak '1{/^$/d}'  somefile
```

The original file will be saved with a `.bak` extension

Comment: Your sed version does not work -- it kills the first empty line it encounters. But the awk version worked fine. I'll update my question with the small wrapper script I wrote around the awk call, to make it seem in-place.

Comment: @Arne .. sorry, I pasted the wrong string - my answer has been updated with the correct `sed` line :-/ ... just bugged me not to have a sed solution earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the first line of all files under the actual directory if the first line is empty : 
 `find -type f | xargs sed -i -e '2,$b' -e '/^$/d'`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for  you:

```
sed '1!b;/^$/d' file
```