# How to delete first blank row in multiple files?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have thousands of text file with empty first row. Is it possible to delete this row in all files at once?

[image]

Comment: only by using notepad++ ?

Comment: Possible shell script solution - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11226938/delete-first-line-of-file-if-its-empty May be easier than doing this in Notepad++ for multiple files.

Comment: While it is possible to find replace in multiple files using `Find in Files` option of notepad++, i don't know how to match only the first blank line.

Comment: I guess it is not necessary using notepad++ only, but it has to be done in windows.

Comment: would a scripting language like autohotkey count?

Comment: Sure. I found this batch script but it's painfully slow. http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f8/use-batch-file-to-remove-first-line-of-text-file-424074.html

Comment: There's no way to do this in notepad++, because regular expressions engine of npp does not handle multiline mode. If it did, then ^ character would match beginning of the file, and there won't be any problems.

Comment: @frikozoid - Ah, not quite ;-) Point 1: Actually, the problem with npp is that you cannot _turn off_ multiline mode! Multiline mode means `^` and `$` match at the beginning and end of every line (_multi_ line) instead of the whole file. Point 2: Actually, despite this problem, there are (at least?) two ways to do this in npp!! See my answer below for the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a bat script like this

```
@echo off
for %%i in (*.txt) do (
more +1 "%%~fi">>temp
del "%%~fi"
ren temp "%%~nxi"
)
```

Save the above code as something.bat and run it at your directory.

Answer (score 1):

This will work using Notepad++ (tested with version 6.2.3):

`\A[\r\n]+`

**Explanation:**

`\A` and `\Z` always match the beginning and end of the entire file, irrespective of the multiline setting.

Note: This regex is slightly more general than the OP asked. It will remove any number of consecutive initial blank rows terminated with any line break sequence (`\r\n`, `\r` or `\n`). 
Nothing is worse than changing thousands of files only to find later that a couple have a different line break sequence or have multiple initial blank lines.

**Alternative:**

Another regex that works is:

`(?<!.)[\r\n]+`

**Explanation:**

This uses negative look-behind, `(?<!)`, to make sure no character exists before the sequence of `CR`s and `LF`s.

Note: You must tick the `. matches newline` check box for this to work.