# How to delete the first line in multiple text files without appending CRLF to the end of the file

Tags: batch-file

I want to delete the first blank row in multiple text files.
I've found a solution to my question here on stackoverflow.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16790431/how-to-delete-first-blank-row-in-multiple-files#*=*

Namely a bat script:

```
@echo off
for %%i in (*.txt) do (
more +1 "%%~fi">>temp
del "%%~fi"
ren temp "%%~nxi"
)
```

However while removing the first blank row this script adds a carriage return and linefeed at the end of the text files.

How do I achieve removing the first blank row without adding a carriage return and linefeed at the end of each text file, using batch files?

Comment: Two points to your question. First of all you should always mark code as code. Secondly you should link to your source, maybe we could catch up a bit more of information to your topic there.

Comment: You are right, I'm sorry, I've edited my question. Thanks....

Answer (score 0):

Try this - `for-in-do` has a bug where some files are processed twice etc when the same filespec is updated in the folder.

```
@echo off
for %%i in (*.txt) do (
   more +1 "%%i">"%%i.temp"
   del "%%i"
)
ren *.temp *.
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but this has the same outcome as the original bat script.....

Comment: `more +1` does not add lines on the end of files.  Are you using Linux formatted files or MAC formatted files?  Do you know how to use a hex viewer on the files to see what is or isn't happening?  `more` does convert TABS to runs of spaces, and if the files are over 64K lines there is another issue.

Comment: I never mentioned the more +1 so I have no clue what you're talking about. |I'm an average computer user. I'm on a Windows machine and I think it are regular text files.

Comment: The files are not over 64K lines by the way.

Comment: The only command in that script which is doing anything to change the files is the `more` command.  You're saying that the script adds `rows` and I assume you mean it adds something at the bottom of the text file.  Is that right?

Comment: On testing with a file that has no Carriage return and line feed on the last line, then `more +1` does add a CRLF to the end of the last line.  It doesn't add a row, just the normal line ending for Windows text files.

Comment: Can you explain how this is a problem in your situation?

Comment: The script is removing the first blank line in multiple text files like I want it to do however at the end of the text files it's adding an extra line namely a blank one. The text files originally all have a text line at the end of them and no blank line....

Comment: As I mentioned above, the last line is having the standard carriage return and linefeed characters added to the end of the line. How does this pose a problem in your code?

Comment: I have a bunch ordinary text files with no empty line at the end of the text files and one blank line at the beginning of the text files. When using the bat script on my windows PC the blank line at the beginning is gone but a blank line is added at the end of the text files. Luckily the problem is gone because I've found a freeware that removes the first blank line of each text file without adding an extra blank line at the end. Thank you for trying to help me....

Comment: Read here for some information on line endings.   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

Comment: Maybe some images will show you what I mean:  http://s28.postimg.org/v3evukga5/Screen_Shot002.jpg   http://s28.postimg.org/8h9khu2jx/Screen_Shot003.jpg

Comment: The first picture is with blank line at the end, the other is without blank line. Screenshots of Notepad++.....

Comment: As I asked earlier - what problem do you have when there is a CRLF on the end of the last line?   FWIW a blank line is **two** CRLF in succession.  A single CRLF at the end of the file is never a problem in normal use.

Comment: I'm using the text files to create a chm file. I don't like the extra blank line because I'm a perfectionist and I was just wandering if it could be removed with a corrected code script.

Comment: On a 32 bit machine you can use a debug in a batch script to remove the last 2 characters, of less than 64 k files.  A powershell or VBS script may help.  Ask another question about removing the first line and not adding CRLF to the last line.

Comment: Do you know a bat script that removes the first line of a bunch of text files while not adding the CRLF to the last line? Thanks in advance.....

Comment: Open another question.  It is normal for lines to have `CRLF` endings and to do what you need requires special handling.

Comment: I'm convinced that my question was/is crystal clear. The need for a special handling in the code is already included in my question. If you don't know the answer it's okay. I'm grateful for your attempts to solve the issue. Thanks......